# Typed in message breaks when receiving a message

Tags: python, multithreading, python-3.x, client-server, chat

i am doing a little client\server threading chat and I have a problem,
if one of the sides is receiving a message while typing one it's breaks the message that is being typed here is a image for illustration

[image]

Here is the threading code:

```
import threading
import socket
class sendTread(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self,soc):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self,name='sender')
        self.s=soc
    def run(self):
        while True:
            self.s.send(bytes(str(input('>>> ')), 'UTF-8'))
            print('sent.')
class recvTread(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self,soc):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self,name='recver')
        self.s=soc
    def run(self):
        while True:
            data=self.s.recv(1024)
            print('\nrecv:',str(data)[2:len(str(data))-1],end="\n>>> ")
```

I understand why it happens but I have no idea how to fix it and I would be happy
for some help and Suggestions :)

Answer (score 0):

You have to approach the problem as a concurrent problem. In your case, the console is a shared resource and what is happening is that the thread of the receiver is using it while is still "taken" by the sender.

You can add a lock that protect the print statements, you can find details about it here:
http://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html#lock-objects